# Map two longs into another object with MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

I'm trying to use mapstruct to generate mappers.
I need to map two doubles (longitude and latitude) into a `org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType.Point`.

I can't find any good examples in the documentation how to do this.

I have tried this (which doesn't work):

```
@Mapping(target="location", expression="java( new com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory().createPoint(new com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate(requestModel.longitude, requestModel.latitude)) )")
```

Sorry about the very long code line.

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work", what exactly does that mean? Do you get an error or exception during generation? Does the generated code not look like what you expected? Btw. you can avoid giving the fully-qualified class names by adding imported types via `@Mapper#imports()`.

Comment: With not working I mean that the result contains a null value for the location property.

Comment: If the result contains a null in "location", the error must be somewhere else. What does the generated code look like? How are you obtaining/calling the mapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the expression doesn't work, I generally try to avoid it as it doesn't play well with refactoring and such, but you can check the generated code to see what's being missed and run it trough a debugger.

You could also handle this in code using [decorators](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_customizing_mappings)

Some untested sample code based on the documentation:

```
 @AfterMapping
 protected void mapPoint(RequestModel requestModel, @MappingTarget TargetEntity result) {
        result.setLocation(
            new GeometryFactory().createPoint(
                new Coordinate(requestModel.longitude,requestModel.latitude
                )
            )
        );
 }
```